# C# access protected field of the object of derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, protected, derived-class

There are two classes:

```
class A
{
   protected IntPtr i;
   public A(A copy)
   {
      this.i = SomeStaticClass.Copy(copy.i);
   }
   protected A(IntPtr ds)
   {
      this.i = ds;
   }
}

class B : A
{
    public B(A init)
    {
        SomeStaticClass.doSomethingWith(init.i); //Cant access this field.
    }

    public void AnotherMethod(A asd)
    {
        SomeStaticClass.doSomethingWith(init.i); //Cant access this field again.
    }
}
```

Field "i" in A class may controll the unmanaged code, so it's should'nt be public.

And I dont wanna make a copy of A (whinch gonna call some unmanaged code to copy i field, whinch is taking some time), this constructor of B is just converting A to B.

Why do objects of class B cant access objectOfA.i field?

Is there any way to fix that problem?

Comment: Just change `SomeStaticClass.doSomethingWith(init.i)` into `SomeStaticClass.doSomethingWith(i)`.

Comment: I need to access init.i, not a this.i, bro

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
class B : A
{
    public B(A init) 
        : base(init)
    {
        SomeStaticClass.doSomethingWith(i);
    }

    public void AnotherMethod(A asd)
    {
        SomeStaticClass.doSomethingWith(i);
    }
}
```

`B` needs to call `A`'s constructor and then the protected member `i` is set. You can then access this protected field in the derived class as usual.

> I need to access `init.i`, not a `this.i`

You can't for obvious reasons. A `protected` member is accessible *within its class* and by *derived* class instances only: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx

Comment: I need to access init.i, not a this.i, bro

Comment: You can't for obvious reasons; a protected member is accessible *within* its class and by *derived* class instances: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you want to construct B object using A object, then you need to call A constructor first and then you can access to i using this in B object.
In your B constructor, call your base (A) constructor.

Then you can call:

```
SomeStaticClass.doSomethingWith(this.i);
```

Comment: A call to a constructor of A is not required at all.

Comment: I think this answers a slightly different question... IMO the real answer here is in the marked dup

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. It's the same answer as mm8, with probably some questionable english, with less code but same idea.

Comment: I already saw PsyWhat answer, saying it needs to access init.i and not this.i, so it was correctly marked as duplicate, and my answers is to a different question, i agree.